# Collatz conjecture with C (range 1-100,000,000) maximum loops

Tags: c, processing-efficiency, collatz

I am making a program that calculates the most loops of the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) between a range of number (1 - 100,000,000) and I need it to be functional in under 4 minutes on a linux system with the

```
command gcc -O0 -m32 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o collatz collatz.c.
```

Any ideas on how to improve the algorithm because after 10,000,000 the program takes too long to complete, keep in mind I can't use multithreading nor pre calculated data.

All answers are welcome, thank you for your time.

```
// Lets find the longest collatz
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// This function finds how many times it took for a number to reach 1
unsigned long int collatz(uint32_t First_num) {
    // steps measures how many times a number needs to reach 1
    uint32_t steps = 1;
    // This is the loop that applies the rules of the collatz conjecture
    while (First_num != 1) {
        (First_num % 2 == 0) ? (First_numm >>= 1) : (First_num = (3 * First_num + 1) / 2);
        steps++;
    }
    return steps;
}

// This is the function that calculates the maximum loops a number needs to reach 1
int max(uint32_t First_num, uint32_t Second_num) {
    // This "if" determines if the number is correct
    if (First_num <= 0 || Second_num <= 0) {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    uint32_t max = 0;
    uint32_t max_num = 0;
    uint32_t i = First_num;
    // This loop is used to find the maximum times the collatz function needs to be used
    for (i; i <= Second_num; i++) {
        printf("The num %u took the most %ld!!!\n", i, collatz(i));
        // This block finds the number with the most loops
        if ((collatz(i)) >= max) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            max = collatz(i);                                                                                              
            max_num = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The num %u took the most %u !!!\n", max_num, max);                                                                                                                                                                        
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
// This is the main function in which the "max" function is used and the user gives his input and gets his output                                                                                                               
int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    if (argc != 3) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        printf("Program needs to be called as './prog num1 num2'\n");                                                                                                                                                                   
        return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    //Users input                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    uint32_t num1 = atoi(argv[1]);                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    uint32_t num2 = atoi(argv[2]);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    // Users input                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    max(num1, num2);                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
//End of the program
```

Comment: Can you cache each result? Then when you 'land on' a number, you know the length of the chain from there.

Comment: What @WeatherVane said - research [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: How do you know it takes too long too complete—did you actually run it to completion, or did you just let it run for a while, some time over 4 minutes, and decide it was taking too long? Because many of the Collatz sequences get larger before they get smaller, so it is conceivable your program exceeded `uint32_t`, got an incorrect result due to wrapping, and entered an infinite loop because of that. Did you check for that?

Comment: What are the lowest input numbers (particularly the second) you know of for which the program does not complete in the desired time?

Comment: `if ((collatz(i)) >= max){                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            max = collatz(i);` is bad because it evaluates `collatz(i)` twice, duplicating work. Remember the result of the first call.

Comment: You could use a simple `int` array as the cache, with a negative value meaning the cached number of steps, and a positive value stored to indicate the *previous* number of the sequence being followed. When you hit a negative number in the cache (or reach 1), you can work back thru the chain you just created overwriting each value with a negative number of steps. But as Eric pointed out, the sequence can go higher than the starting point, so you need to find out how high it does go, using your more brutal approach.

Comment: FYI: When you start with 80,049,391, the Collatz sequence has 572 steps and the maximum value reached has 16 digits: 2,185,143,829,170,100.  When you start with 63,728,127, the Collatz sequence has 949 steps, and the maximum value reached is  966,616,035,460.  The code must use 64-bit types for the calculations for values up to 100,000,000.  It took my machine (2019 16" MacBook Pro, 2.6 GHz 6-core Intel Core i7), 44.6s to calculate all the values up to 100,000,000 using a brute-force algorithm with just the summary printing.  It would take far longer if it printed intermediate results.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: What’s wrong with your system? `static uint64_t CountCollatz(uint64_t i) { uint64_t Count = 0; for (uint64_t x = i; 1 < x; ++Count) x = x % 2 ? 3*x+1 : x/2; return Count; } int main(void) { uint64_t max = 0; for (uint64_t i = 1; i <= 100000000; ++i) { uint64_t count = CountCollatz(i); if (max < count) max = count; } printf("Maximum = %" PRIu64 ".\n", max); }` with the obvious `#include` directives takes 21.8 seconds on a 2017 3.3 GHz dual-core i7. Scaled for CPU speed, that would be 27.7 seconds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It's probably that I'm counting both the maximum steps and the maximum values (and recording which input value yields each maximum).  In general, the number with the longest Collatz sequence isn't the one that reaches the largest value, and vice versa.  But even with that overhead, it shows that 4 minutes is not an unreasonable time limit even for numbers up to 100 million.  Of course, number of cores is almost irrelevant — this is the epitome of compute-bound processing and only by writing threaded code to sub-divide the work would the number of cores affect the timing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I find, to my complete chagrin, that the makefile I was using was not optimizing the code at all.  With `-O3`, the runtimes for my code and your code are about 27-28s each — and a memoizing version takes about 5s.  Your code is normally about 1 second faster, which I will attribute to mine doing a little more work because it tracks more statistics.

Answer (score 5):

**Bug**

`3 * First_num + 1` readily overflows.  Need more work (a wider type).  [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77335830/collatz-conjecture-with-c-range-1-100-000-000-maximum-loops/77335960#comment136337802_77335830)

**Drop debug output**

```
for (i;i<=Second_num;i++){
  // printf("The num %u took the most %ld!!!\n",i,collatz(i))
```

> Any ideas on how to improve the algorithm because after 10,000,000 the program takes too long to complete

**Avoid re-calculation**

```
// if ((collatz(i)) >= max) {
//   max = collatz(i);
unsigned long cc = collatz(i);
if (cc >= max) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  max = cc
```

**Save prior work**

(or at least some of it.)

```
#define PRIOR_N (100u*1000*1000)
static uint32_t prior[PRIOR_N];

// This function finds how many times it took for a number to reach 1
unsigned long int collatz(uint32_t First_num) {
  if (First_num < PRIOR_N && prior[First_num] && First_num > 1) {
    return prior[First_num];
  }
  ...
```

---

After re-work to prevent overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define PRIOR_N (100u*1000*1000)
static uint32_t prior[PRIOR_N];

// This function finds how many times it took for a number to reach 1
unsigned collatz(uint64_t n) {
  if (n < PRIOR_N && prior[n]) {
    return prior[n]; // Use prior work if available.
  }
  // Applies the rules of the Collatz conjecture.
  if (n > 1) {
    unsigned cc;
    if(n % 2 == 0) {
      cc = collatz(n >> 1) + 1;
    } else {
      if (n >= (ULLONG_MAX - 1)/3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Overflow\n");
        return UINT_MAX/2;
      }
      cc = collatz((3 * n + 1) / 2) + 1;
    }
    if (n < PRIOR_N) {
      prior[n] = cc;  // Save work.
    }
    return cc;
  }
  return n;
}
```

```
// 4.5 seconds.
The num 63728127 took the most 593 !!!
```

---

**Empirical: Reverse iteration order**

I reversed the order, going from most to least and it took 1/6 less time. (total 3.75 s)  TBD why.

---

Aside: OP's code is loose with types changes.  Improved code would avoid that.

Comment: There even better ways to re-use prior work.  But I'll leave this as an example for OP.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- there is a typo in the update formula in the body of the `while` loop:

  ```
      (First_num % 2 == 0) ? (First_numm>>=1) : (First_num = (3*First_num+1)/2);
  ```

  There is an extra `m` in `First_numm`. Using an `if` statement with proper spacing is recommended for readability:

  ```
      if (First_num % 2 == 0) {
          First_num >>= 1;
      } else {
          First_num = (3 * First_num + 1) / 2;
      }
  ```
- timing the program with debugging output is bogus: producing the output may take longer than the computation itself.
- as posted, `collatz(i)` is computed 3 times: computing the value once per iteration and storing it in a temporary variable will reduce the time with very little effort.
- timing the program compiled with optimisations disabled is only of pedagogical value: on my M2 macbook, the execution time for 100 million is 37.2 seconds with **-O3** and just a little more with **-O0**, which is very surprising. The timing difference may be more important with gcc generating 32-bit code.
- you make the silent assumption that no intermediary value exceeds the range of `uint32_t`, which is non obvious for starting points as large as 100 million.  As a matter of fact, no less than 961803 numbers produce chains with at least one number greater or equal to  2<sup>32</sup>!

  Using 64-bit arithmetics produces a different output:

  ```
  The num 63728127 took the most 593 !!!
  ```
- the formula to update `First_num` in the odd case can be simplified as `First_num += (First_num + 1) / 2`.
- you could even use a branchless formula to update `First_num`:

  ```
  First_num = (First_num & -(First_num % 2)) + (First_num + 1) / 2;
  ```

  However this does not seem to produce any runtime gains.

Taking the above remarks into consideration, the modified version below completes in about 28 seconds:

```
// This function finds how many times it took for a number to reach 1
unsigned long int collatz(uint32_t First_num) {
    // steps measures how many times a number needs to reach 1
    unsigned long int steps = 1;
    // This is the loop that applies the rules of the collatz conjecture
    unsigned long long n = First_num;
    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n >>= 1;
        } else {
            // Detect potential overflow
            if (n > ULLONG_MAX - ULLONG_MAX / 2) {
                printf("overflow: %u -> %llu\n", First_num, n);
                return 0;
            }
            n += (n + 1) / 2;
        }
        steps++;
    }
    return steps;
}
```

Adding an array to cache previous results improves the timing by a factor of 10 for 100 million:

```
// This function finds how many times it took for a number to reach 1
unsigned long int collatz(uint32_t First_num) {
#define CACHE_SIZE  100000000
#if CACHE_SIZE
    static uint32_t cache[CACHE_SIZE];
#endif
    // steps measures how many times a number needs to reach 1
    unsigned long int steps = 1;
    // This is the loop that applies the rules of the collatz conjecture
    unsigned long long n = First_num;
    while (n > 1) {
#if CACHE_SIZE
        if (n < CACHE_SIZE && cache[n]) {
            steps += cache[n] - 1;
            break;
        }
#endif
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n >>= 1;
        } else {
            // Detect potential overflow
            if (n > ULLONG_MAX - ULLONG_MAX / 2) {
                printf("overflow: %u -> %llu\n", First_num, n);
                return 0;
            }
            n += (n + 1) / 2;
        }
        steps++;
    }
#if CACHE_SIZE
    if (First_num < CACHE_SIZE) {
        cache[First_num] = steps;
    }
#endif
    return steps;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The extra `m` in `First_numm`

Comment: Re “the formula to update `First_num` in the odd case can be simplified as `First_num += (First_num + 1) / 2`”: This not right. The defined chain from 5 would be 5➝16➝8➝4➝2➝1. Your change would give 5➝3. Also, the count has to be adjusted when using a shortcut.